# selecting between multiple dataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have multiple dataFrames, say df_0, df_1, dg_0, dg_1, with the same index and columns.

eg

```
df_0=pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,1,2],"B":[3,3,0]})

df_1=pd.DataFrame({"A":[3,5,1],"B":[2,1,1]})

dg_0=pd.DataFrame({"A":['a','b','c'],"B":['d','e','f']})

dg_1=pd.DataFrame({"A":['g','h','i'],"B":['j','k','l']})
```

I would like to select between dg_0 and dg_1 according to whether df_0 or df_1 is bigger.

So the final output should be:

```
df_out=pd.DataFrame({"A":['g','h','c'],"B":['d','e','l']})
```

As an intermediate step, I can define dh be the idxmax of df_0 and df_1, which in this case should be:

```
dh=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,1,0],"B":[0,0,1]})
```

And then try to use dh to select between dg_0 and dg_1.

I think this works to create dh:

```
dh=pd.concat([df_0,df_1],axis=1,keys=['0','1']).groupby(levels=1).idxmax().applymap(lambda x:x[0])
```

But I am stumped how to get df_out.  Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: What is the desired behavior if the values in df_0 and df_1 are equal?

Comment: Not sure.  I am just trying to optimize something, and for now I don’t have an opinion about ties.  Will probably want to choose either dg_0 or dg_1 as default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and  [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```py
df_mask = df_0.gt(df_1)
df_out = dg_0[df_mask]
df_out.update(dg_1.mask(df_mask))
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  g  d
1  h  e
2  c  l
```

---

To make it scalable to multiple dataframes and columns:

- *Option 1:*

```py
dfs = [df_0, df_1] # list of dataframes
dgs = [dg_0, dg_1] # second list of dataframes (dgs)

# Concatenate dataframes
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
dg = pd.concat(dgs, axis=1)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))

# Get the indexes of maximum values per target-columns
ncol = dfs[0].shape[1]
idx = {k: df.iloc[:, i::ncol].idxmax(1) for i,k in enumerate(dfs[0].columns)}

# Retrieve data from dg (target output)
df_out = pd.DataFrame({k: [dg.iloc[i,v] for i,v in idx[k].iteritems()] for k in idx})
```

- *Option 2 (mask):*

```py
dfs = [df_0, df_1] # list of dataframes
dgs = [dg_0, dg_1] # second list of dataframes (dgs)

# Concatenate dataframes
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
dg = pd.concat(dgs, axis=1)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
dg.columns = range(len(dg.columns))

# Get data for target-columns
ncol = dfs[0].shape[1]
col_data = {k: df.iloc[:, i::ncol] for i,k in enumerate(dfs[0].columns)}

# Mask non-maximum values per target-columns
col_mask = {k: ~col_data[k].eq(col_data[k].max(1), axis='rows') for k in idx}

# Retrieve data from dg (target output)
df_out = pd.DataFrame({k: dg.iloc[:, i::ncol].mask(col_mask[k]).stack().values for i,k in enumerate(col_mask)})
```

The output for both of them is the same as the original answer.

Comment: Very nice, thanks!!  Was not familiar with those.

Comment: You're welcome! Here, if the values are equal, it's gonna return the value from `dg_1`. If you want the other way around, replace `dg_1` by `dg_0` and vice-versa.

Comment: I actually have two collection of frames, df_0, ... df_n and dg_0, ..., dg_n, and want to select from dg_i's according to max of df_i's.  Don't see a way to generalize this solution to handle the frames all at once, but n is small, so iterating this solution with pair-wise max should work fine.

Comment: @newAccountHolder, I've updated the answer to include a scalable approach so that it works regardless of either the number of dataframes or the columns from dataframes. It assumes, however, that all dataframes share index and columns.

Comment: Awesome, that's great.  Learned a lot here, thanks for your help.